# Wordpress thickbox/lightbox/fancybox/ANYTHING in admin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, wordpress

I am building a custom Wordpress plugin for a customer and I'd like the *admin* page to utilize some kind of modal popup. I've tried ThickBox, LightBox, and Fancybox, and none of them seem to work. ThickBox does work, but I am unable to resize it, but I read the Wordpress modified it for use exclusively with the media uploader.

I've tried those three, and I load the scripts properly with wp_enqueue_script. I get no errors, just nothing happens when I apply the attributes as outlined by each product.

Any help or successful method suggestion is welcomed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a more barebones modal option such as jqModal? http://dev.iceburg.net/jquery/jqModal/